# Disable Apache2 default SSL site

Tags: apache-2.4

The following is working fine for `http` and all non-configured domains or IP address requests are getting `404`, however, it doesn't work for the default `https` site and still goes the first `https` site configured. What am I missing?

This works:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't and requests go to the first `https` site.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please describe "doesn't work" in more detail. What happens if you try to reach this virtualhost?

Comment: It goes to the first https site like it does without default site configuration. I also updated my question to explain that.